# Communication between winforms application multiple instance

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

I have a winforms application installed on a terminal service that is accessed by multiple users. This application supports multiple instances.

After the user logs in, some settings are loaded, and so on occur with other users.

First I would like to get all already open instances and get them a particular setting. The intention is not to leave open a new instance if there is already open with the same settings.

It is possible?

PS: On the login screen, the user can select from a combo box the company you want to work, so he can open an instance with the company "A" and then open another instance of the company "B" thus have two instances, the same user and company different.

Comment: See this article about creating a single instance application, except you will need to modify it so that the system mutex name is based on something from the user's account information, such as the username.  That way the application is single instance within a single profile. http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html

Comment: The application can not be single instance because a user may open more than once, but using different settings, and at this time have to check instance settings already open to know if you open another.

Comment: You should explain that requirement better in your question.  It will help you get better answers from people if they understand that requirement.

Comment: The requirement is not defined well and it's not clear what you need. It doesn't seem to be related to communication between applications or counting open instances but maybe related to counting open sessions for a user.

Comment: I have not yet session control, needed to control whether a new instance may or may not be opened by checking instances now open ... thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a `Mutex` in your application's `program.cs`.

Our application is actually a collection of apps that begins with a central EXE, and that EXE can then launch others.  In addition, there are three flavors of the main application.  We need to ensure that only one of each flavor is open at once for each user context.

We use this:

```
Boolean createdNew;
var mut = new Mutex(true, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, out createdNew);
if (!createdNew)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(appName))
        return;

    var processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
    foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName))
    {
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(appName))
        {
            if (userVars.SendDebugOutput)
            {
                //we found one already running...do anything about it?
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You will want to modify the mutex creation to include a string that includes the information you need to use in differentiating instances.

This would be put in the `program.cs` code page, *before* the line that starts your main form, e.g. `Application.Run(new frmMyMainForm());`.